# VScode intellisense bug with Office-js and Angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, intellisense, office-js

I have an Office-JS project based on Angular 6 which is running fine. To get Word and Office objects available in a component though, I need to add a 

  `declare const Office: any;
  declare const Word: any;`
 
somewhere in the component.ts file.

But VScode then doesn't intellisense all properties and methods correctly when I declare them like that, which is inconvenient to say the least. But when i remove those lines, intellisense DOES show all properties and methods just fine! But then the `ng build` or `ng run start` fail because of `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Word'` (in methods that use `Word.run(async (ctx) =>{ ... etc..`

Is this a bug somewhere? Is there a model I can import from '@microsoft/office-js' so i can declare the office objects with their correct types so intellisense knows all about their properties and not just about SOME??

Comment: I dont have points for a bounty but does anybody have any ideas?